# SharePoint 2010: Set SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail via EcmaScript

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ecmascript-5

I have a custom ribbon button which creates a Site Group with a predefined set of permissions. This is all done using **EcmaScript** and so far is working 100%.

The only settings I can't seem to initialise on the new Site Group using EcmaScript are those relating to membership requests (i.e. **SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail**)

Does anyone know how to set this property using the client object model?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What happens when you attempt to set the properties?

Comment: The property doesn't seem to exist on the client-side Web object. If using the server object model, this setting is controlled via the SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see it listed in the [SP.Web Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee549149.aspx). Here is the definition of the SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail setter from Reflector:

```
if (!this.Site.WebApplication.RequestAccessEnabled)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(SPResource.GetString("EmailServiceNotConfigured", new object[0]));
}
if (SPWebService.ContentService.CreateActiveDirectoryAccounts)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(SPResource.GetString("RequestAccessNotAllowedOnVirtualServer", new object[0]));
}
if (!this.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    throw new SPException(SPResource.GetString("RequestAccessUniqueWebs", new object[0]));
}
SPGlobal.FilterNullSize(value, 0xff, "RequestAccessEmail");
this.Request.SetRequestAccessInfo(this.Url, null, 0, true, value.Trim());
```

I don't think you will be able to duplicate this functionality using the ECMAScript object model.

Comment: I'd guessed this functionality wasn't available, so thank-you for the evidence and confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to set the SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail to an empty string, which has the same effect as setting SPWeb.RequestAccessEnabled to false.

Comment: The original question specifically requested that client-side EcmaScript (i.e. javascript) be used as the action is being triggered by a ribbon button. Powershell scripts can't be used here.

Comment: I was just pointing out that in PowerShell setting the email address to empty has the same effect in the UI as unchecking the box.  I thought this might be the same for other parts of the API, including client side object model.